# Why does my component keep rendering in all routes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, glamorous

I am attempting to render a component when I enter a url that does not exists. However, the component keeps rendering in all routes. I am using `react-router-dom@4.1.1`. This are the routes that I set up:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import glamorous from "glamorous";
import ElementList from "./elementlist";
import AddElement from "./addelement";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";

const Styling = glamorous.div({
  minHeight: 5,
  minWidth: 8
});

const NavRouter = () => (
  <Styling>
    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={ElementList} />
    <Route path="/addelement" component={(props: 
       RouteComponentProps<{}>) => (
         <AddElement onSubmitSuccess={() => props.history.push("/")} />
       )} />
    <Route path="*" exact={true} component={NotFound}/>
  </Styling>
);

export default NavRouter;
```

This is my `NotFound` component:

```
import * as React from "react";


const NotFound = () => (
  <h1>The page that you are looking is not there.</h1>
);

export default NotFound;
```

The issue that I am currently facing is that the message: `The page that you are looking is not there.` keeps popping up on the `/` and `/addelement` route when I changed the URL. I am having a hard time trying to make the message appear only when I go to a route that is not defined. Initially, I tried to switch the routes and make the more "detailed" route at the top like this:

```
const NavRouter = () => (
  <Styling>
    <Route path="/addelement" component={(props: 
       RouteComponentProps<{}>) => (
         <AddElement onSubmitSuccess={() => props.history.push("/")} />
       )} />
    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={ElementList} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
  </Styling>
);
```

However, it did not solve the issue. Is there a way to prevent the message from appearing on every route that I go to except for routes that are not defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a [`<Switch>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) component. Per the documentation:

> #### How is this different than just using a bunch of `<Route>`s?
>
> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route *exclusively*. In contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders *inclusively*. Consider this code:
>
> ```
> <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
> <Route path="/:user" component={User}/>
> <Route component={NoMatch}/>
> ```
>
> If the URL is `/about`, then `<About>`, `<User>`, and `<NoMatch>` will all render because they all match the path. This is by design, allowing us to compose `<Route>`s into our apps in many ways, like sidebars and breadcrumbs, bootstrap tabs, etc.
>
> Occasionally, however, we want to pick only one `<Route>` to render. If we’re at `/about` we don’t want to also match `/:user` (or show our “404” page).

Thus, import it from `react-router-dom`:

```
import { Route, RouteComponentProps, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then apply it like so (note there is no need for `path="*"`):

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact={true} component={ElementList} />
  <Route path="/addelement" component={(props: 
     RouteComponentProps<{}>) => (
       <AddElement onSubmitSuccess={() => props.history.push("/")} />
     )} />
  <Route component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```